# Showing route on map

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps

I am developing a windows phone for railways.I want to show the  route of train.
How to do this?
Google direction service gives route only from origin to destinations.But I want to show the whole route in which train goes

Indian railway

Comment: I'm not familiar on this topic and this is totally a guess; may be you can define multiple origin and destinations.

Comment: You need the coordinates of the railroad track.  What country?  That will determine how easy it is to get that data.